# how to bind xml to JSTree control in c#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, xml

i retrieve xml of the format as below via webservice. How can we bind this xml with JSTree. Looking for an example of binding and capturing the OnSelect event of the node

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfTerm_Child xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
 <Term_Child>
<TermID>2021</TermID>
<Name>A. Geographic locations</Name>
<ParentID>0</ParentID>
</Term_Child>
<Term_Child>
 <TermID>3602</TermID>
<Name>Oceania</Name>
<ParentID>2021</ParentID>
</Term_Child>
<Term_Child>
<TermID>3604</TermID>
<Name>Australasia</Name>
<ParentID>3602</ParentID>
</Term_Child>
<Term_Child>
<TermID>3621</TermID>
<Name>New Zealand</Name>
<ParentID>3604</ParentID>
</Term_Child>
<Term_Child>
<TermID>3619</TermID>
<Name>Pacific Islands</Name>
<ParentID>3604</ParentID>
</Term_Child>
 <Term_Child>
<TermID>3585</TermID>
<Name>Polynesia</Name>
 <ParentID>3619</ParentID>
 </Term_Child>
 </ArraryOfTerm>
```

Comment: suggest you map the xml to JSON with proper structure required by plugin

Comment: okay. I can get the same data from webservice in JSON format. How do you bind JSON format to tree and capture OnSelected event

Comment: data struture and events are covered in the documentation...what part of docs do you have trouble following?

Comment: I looked at the documentation again at http://www.jstree.com but the documentation is not very user friendly. I m looking for a complete example which will bind the results retrieved from the webservice. I want to give each root and child nodes an ID, and once a node is clicked i want to show some information in a popup box etc

Comment: you won't find an example because you need to map the xml into format that jstree recognizes following the data structure in docs. How are you retrieving xml? Also, do you only need to create a list...or do you need a lot of features in jstree. Is advanced plugin if all you need is list and clcik event and code for that is simple

Comment: I have written a web client in c# which calls a web method in a local webservice and receive data in JSON format.

Comment: just thought of simpler approach, create html list first, then let jstree activate... list html from json or xml is easy to do. JSON easiest, can you post JSON data example

Comment: exmple parsing xml to list, and then initiating tree: http://jsfiddle.net/khTLM/  I assume countries need to be nested but your xml has no nesting, or tag for main node